# Avoid Race condition

Tags: amazon-s3, conditional-statements

I have a simple code that create a folder structure in a specific place.

I am trying to have the code create and hidden `.okay.dat` file in every single folder in order to allow `AWS S3` to successfully upload everything to the cloud when I came across a race condition.

Can someone advise the best way to avoid it?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print 'This script will generate the standard tree structure'

while True:
        import  os
        aw_directory = "/mnt/sdb1/9999_testfolder/"
        for child in os.listdir(aw_directory):
            project_path = os.path.join(aw_directory, child)
            if os.path.isdir(project_path):

#GUARD AGAINST RACE CONDITION TO BE ADDED
#               open('001_DATALAB/.OKAY.dat', 'w').close()
#    except OSError as exc: # Guard against race condition
#       if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
#           raise
#with open(okaystudio.dat, "w") as f:
#    f.write("hidden file for AWS3")

                a       = os.path.join(project_path, '001_DATALAB/')
                open('001_DATALAB/OKAYstudio.dat', 'w').close()
                b       = os.path.join(project_path, '001_DATALAB/001_Rushes')

                if not os.path.exists(a):
                    original_umask_a = os.umask(0)
                    os.makedirs(a, mode=0777)
                    os.umask(original_umask_a)
                if not os.path.exists(b):
                    original_umask_b = os.umask(0)
                    os.makedirs(b, mode=0777)
                    os.umask(original_umask_b)
```

Comment: Okay, what's the race condition?

Comment: Basically the script can't execute the code because is trying to write a file in a folder that doesn't exist yet.
Ideally the folder should be created and the okay.dat file in it only after the folder creation

Comment: You haven't clearly explained the purpose of `.okay.dat`, but if it is supposed to indicate that a folder is ready to sync (?) then it seems apparent that you should not *try* to create it until after you have verified that the folder exists, or until you have created the folder and presumably any contents and children of the folder.  Creating it early would actually *cause* a (different) race condition if the S3 synchronization (?) process is running independently from this script. (The condition here does not actually appear to be a race condition, just a design error.)

Comment: Yes the okay.dat file fill the folder as the S3 storage doesn't upload empty folders (the folder concept on amazon clouds don't really exists that's why I need a file into it)
EDIT The s3 sync runs as a cronjob overnight. Ideally I would like to have the script creating the folder and the file in it in one script. Is it possible? If so, how?